# Android with Material DesignSupport doesn't hide toolbar

Tags: android, material-design

I'm following [this tutorial on hiding/showing toolbar when list is scrolling](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part3%29/).

If I use the source project works fine but when I'm trying to create an example, it doesn't work.
I'm having a problem hiding the toolbar and tabs.

This is my activity main.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/color_accent_pink"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

MyAdapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>    
{
    int mSize;
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public MyAdapter(int mSize, Context context) {
        this.mSize = mSize;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_recyclerview,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText("position: "+position);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSize;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView textView;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my Fragment with Recycler View;

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

    protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    public int mSize;

    public int getmSize() {
        return mSize;
    }

    public void setmSize(int mSize) {
        this.mSize = mSize;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view,container,false);
        Log.i("mSizeOnCreateView", String.valueOf(mSize));
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(mSize,getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        return v;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the version of recycler view

with

```
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
```

everything was resolved.